# What is the difference in the persistent shopping cart between community and enterprise?

Tags: magento-enterprise, cart, persistent

We are using Magento enterprise and I see persistent shopping cart code in a separate enterprise section. I wanted to know if there is a difference in the persistent shopping cart between magento enterprise and community editions?

Is there a difference in functionality or is the enterprise code there to make it work with full page cache?